# Usercontrol display error in C# Designer

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, user-controls

I've created a usercontrol in the C# (ASP.NET) designer. It works fine (when I compile / run) and doesn't kick out any errors. I'm using it in a GridView, if that makes a difference.

Sometimes, when I'm in the designer (for the page, not the control) it gives me a red box and tells me it can't display the user control. Switching to source view and then back to the designer (which usually solves problems like this) doesn't work, but closing and re-opening VS (2008 Professional) does.

It's not a huge issue, but it's pretty annoying. Any ideas of what might be going on here or what I can do about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue when i inherit a form or usercontrol , it seems that visual studio has a trouble with inheritance specially deep inheritance

Answer (score 1):

What about just closing the designer view and reopening it, does it work after that? I have had problems like that if all the member variables arent initialized.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what's happenning is that several users have encountered a bug, but have not reported it. In consequence, Microsoft hasn't fixed it.

The result is more users encounter the bug, but don't report it...

If you have a reproducible bug, create a small sample that reliably reproduces it, then file a bug report at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/.

Otherwise, someone else will encounter the bug, ...